# maven works with assembly:assembly but fails with assembly:single

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project that is packed successfully using mvn assembly:assembly command, however I saw that this goal is [deprecated](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html) so I tried to use mvn assembly:singe as suggested, but now I'm getting the following error:

**[WARNING] Missing POM for jarfile...**

**[WARNING] [DEPRECATION] moduleSet/binaries section detected in root-project assembly.**

"jarfile" is a jar that exists in my local repository. Any idea why it is found for assembly:assembly goal but not for assembly:single ?

Comment: The warning Missing POM for ... means that you are using a dependency which does not exist.

Comment: So why I don't see it when I'm using assembly:assembly ?

Comment: Can you show the complete log output of Maven?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by generating pom file for this jar, not sure why it wasn't required for assembly:assembly, but I have now other problems when running assembly:plugin. I noticed however that assembly:assembly is deprecated only from 2.4 and I'm using 2.3 so I will use it instead.